# jquery - leaving the hover state

Tags: jquery

I have 2 div tag. The first contains a table. The second contains some text. When the page is loaded both div have no background-color. When there is an hover on a td of the first div, the second div background-color is set to yellow (see code below). My problem is that when I leave the table with the mouse, the background of the second div stays yellow. I would like the color to be remove on leaving the hover state. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

My HTML :

```
​<div id="div-one">
    <table>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>                   
    </table>
</div>

​<div id="div-two">
    some text
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).on("hover", "#div-one td", function() { 

    $("#div-two").css("background-color":"yellow");
});​
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events separately - which is actually a "hover" event:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $("#div-two").css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#div-two").css("background-color", "");
    }
}, "#div-one td");​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/6CGyz/)**

Comment: Hello Didier. Your seem to work, actually it works, but I am confused with you syntax. What is the last "#divone" used for?

Comment: Sorry i copy pasted my demo code, i've corrected the selectors. The last parameter is the "selector" parameter of the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method: it comes last when using the eventMap syntax (check the documentation).

Comment: +1 Interesting syntax for binding several events to one element.

Answer (score 4):

There is an error, you are using `:` when defining single property.
When defining a single property you should use `,`

```
// For single property
$("#selector").css("property", "value");

//Define multiple properties
$("#anotherselector").css({
  property1: value1,
  property2: value2,
});
```

#### Solution

Use this

```
$("#div-one td").mouseover(function() {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color","yellow");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color","white");
});
```

Or, if you want to keep on using `.on()` method

```
$(document).on("hover", "#div-one td", function() {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color", "yellow");
}).on("mouseout", "#div-one td", function() {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color", "white");
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TG76q/1/)

Comment: Hello Starx. Thanks for the help. Your code seem to be work. But I have a problem. Inside my td I have li tags. And so When i am with the mouse in the middle of the td the color changes as if i left the td tag eventhough i am in the middle of it. Can I solve this problem with z-index?

Comment: @Marc, in order to fix that, instead of `hover` user `mouseenter` event, the rest of the code should work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#div-one td").hover(
  function () {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color":"yellow");
  },
  function () {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color":"red"); //or some other color
  }
);
```

Comment: Hello I can't use this syntax as all my content is loaded through ajax calls. Thanks anyway....

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
<div id="#div-one">
```

be

```
​<div id="div-one">
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use '#' symbol inside

i.e. `<div id="#div-one">`​ instead of `<div id="div-one">`​

Use `,` insteaf of `:`

i.e.

```
$("#div-two").css("background-color":"yellow");
$("#div-two").css("background-color","yellow");
```

So  content would be like this:

```
<div id="div-one">
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>                   
</table>
</div>

<div id="div-two">
some text
</div>
```

and your Script would be,

```
$(document).on({
mouseover: function() {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color", "#F9FC02");
},
mouseout: function() {
    $("#div-two").css("background-color", "");
  }
}, "#div-one td");​
```

[Checkout Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CGyz/12/)