# How to reverse hover state with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My assignment requires that I use jquery only. Doesn't seem practical but I'm limited. I was able to figure out how to do a hover state but when the styles get applied, it stays. So check this out..

```
$(".cta-button").css({
      background: "#476887",
      "text-align": "center",
      width: "173px",
      height: "40px",
      margin: "62px auto 33px",
      cursor: "pointer"
    });
    $(".cta-button").hover(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "#509de5");
    });
```

Of course when I'm no longer hovering, I want it to revert back to it's original background color. How do I go about doing this? Thanks!!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Did you read the documentation at all? `hover()` accepts **two** functions, one for the mouse entering, and one for the mouse leaving.

Comment: Read documentation of libraries....

Comment: Use `$(this).addClass(...)` rather than `.css()` in the hover() function, then you can easily `removeClass()` on either the second arg of hover or mouseout().

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480968/jquery-leaving-the-hover-state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by using the [`hover` method of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

As stated in the docs, this method can accept one to two arguments, the first one is called the `handlerIn` which can be translated as the hover state, mouse enter, etc and the `handlerOut` which corressponds to the 'mouse leave'

So to achieve what you want you can try something like this

```
$('DOM_NODE').hover(mouseEnter, mouseLeave);
function mouseEnter() {
     // do something when the mouse enters the dom node 
};
function mouseLeave() {
     // do something when the mouse leaves the dom node
};
```

Comment: mouseEnter not mouserEnter

Comment: This was all in the documentation and I should have read it first. I'll spend more time reading through docs rather than google searching. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add mouseover event
[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeaf86j3/)

```
$(".cta-button").css({
      background: "#476887",
      "text-align": "center",
      width: "173px",
      height: "40px",
      margin: "62px auto 33px",
      cursor: "pointer"
    });
    $(".cta-button").hover(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "#509de5");
    }).mouseover(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "#476887");
    });
```